# How to minimize a set of trigonometric equations

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, optimization, maxima-minima

I would like to minimize an angle based on two rational numbers $a,b$. The trigonometric equations read,

$
\cos\theta = \left(a-\frac{b}{2}\right)-\cos(1.6^\circ)\left(a-\frac{b}{2}\right)+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}b\sin\left(1.6^\circ\right)+1
$

and,

$
\sin\theta = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}b\left(1-\cos(1.6^\circ)\right)-\sin(1.6^\circ)\left(a-\frac{b}{2}\right).
$

The only constraint that I have for the angle $\theta$ is that it's within the range $-5 \leq \theta \leq 5$. Someone mentioned how I could use a Jacobian matrix to minimize the angle, but I am not too familiar with that procedure. Is there another way to minimize the angle, and thus solving for the set of equations?

EDIT: I have read upon other similar problems and made a bit of progress but I am not sure if I am going in the right direction. I solved for theta in the first equation,

$ \theta = \arccos \left( \left(a - \frac{b}{2} \right)(1-\cos(1.6^\circ)) + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}b\sin(1.6^\circ)+1 \right)$.

From here, I think that to minimize $\theta$ I take two partial derivatives with respect to $a,b$. From this I have read that I can find the critical points of the differentiated $\arccos$ function, and then find the set of $a,b$ that overall minimize the problem. I just don't know how the initial constraint can be added into the problem.

Comment: Do you want to find the a and b which minimize $\theta$ in that range?

Comment: @Paul Yes! Sorry I am new to this.

Comment: It's not clear to me that there are rational $a, b$ that satisfy those two equations.

Comment: @eyeballfrog I had solved this equation by inspection, and there are rational numbers $a,b$ that do satisfy the equation. The main problem is that I need one of the angles to be close to $1.6^\circ$, and I'd need to minimize the other angle. Now, I do think that the pair $a,b$ won't be rational, but I can approximate the two numbers as rational so they can be close to the actual answer.

Comment: "I had solved this equation by inspection": please show us...

Comment: @YvesDaoust I wrote some code to iterate through a closed set of rational numbers to solve for two angles that are within the range $-5\leq \theta \leq 5$. But here I am trying to figure out which values of $a,b$ can give me an angle $1.6$ and another one within the range.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that no rational pair $(a,b)$ can satisfy the equation (they belong to an ellipse of irrational coefficients).

If you lift this constraint, the system of equations is linear in $a,b$ and will have a solution for any $\theta$. Hence the smallest value is $-5°$.

Comment: How do you know that the pair (a,b) belong to an ellipse of irrational coefficients? I somehow tried to calculate the critical points of the eq, and graphed the pairs, and also got an elliptical graph, but I don't know if it's the same.